Weighted shift operators with absolutely equal weights are unitarily equivalent
I have been stuck on the following exercise from Elementary Functional Analysis by Barbara MacCluer:
Exercise 2.10. Let $\{a_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{g_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ for $\ell^2$ (here, we are working in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ not $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$). The unique operator $W$ satisfying $W(g_n) = \alpha_n g_{n + 1}$ for all $n$ is called a weighted shift.
Let $\{a_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$, $\{b_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be bounded sequences with $|a_n| = |b_n|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $W$ and $V$ be the associated weighted shifts (i.e., $W(g_n) = a_n g_{n + 1}, V(g_n) = b_n g_{n + 1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$). Show that there is a unitary $U: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ with $U^{-1} W U = V$. We say that $W$ and $V$ are unitarily equivalent.
Progress: I was given the hint to use a diagonal operator $U: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ given by $D(g_n) = d_n g_n$ and $|d_n| = 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For me, it's clear that $D$ is unitary, with inverse $D^{-1}(g_n) = \overline{d_n}g_n$. However, I am unsure how to define the sequence of complex numbers $\{d_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$. I was thinking something along the  lines of $d_n := \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ or something similar (such a definition of $d_n$ did not yield $D^{-1}WD = V$ for me), but what if $|a_n| = |b_n| = 0$? Any help would be much appreciated.

In order to obtain a good idea of what the terms of the sequence $(d_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ should be, let's suppose for the moment that a linear isometry $D:\ell^{2} \to \ell^{2}$ is given satisfying $D(g_{n}) = d_{n}g_{n}$ with $|d_{n}| = 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $D^{-1}WD = V$. Then given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $V(g_{n}) = b_{n}g_{n+1}$ while $(D^{-1}WD)(g_{n}) = d_{n} (D^{-1}W)(g_{n}) = a_{n}d_{n} D^{-1}(g_{n+1}) = a_{n}d_{n}d_{n+1}^{-1}$. So $b_{n}d_{n+1} = a_{n}d_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
As a result, the values of the sequence $(d_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ should be chosen such that $b_{n}d_{n+1} = a_{n}d_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Recursively define the sequence $(d_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $d_{1} := 1$ and
$$d_{n+1} := \begin{cases} b_{n}^{-1}a_{n}d_{n} & \text{if $b_{n} \neq 0$}, \\ 1 & \text{if }b_{n} = 0. \end{cases}$$
As $|a_{n}| = |b_{n}|$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $|d_{n}| = 1$ and $b_{n}d_{n+1} = a_{n}d_{n}$ both hold for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Now define $D:\ell^{2} \to \ell^{2}$ as the unique linear isometry satisfying $D(g_{n}) = d_{n}g_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which can be done as $|d_{n}| = 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The relation $b_{n}d_{n+1} = a_{n}d_{n}$ implies that
$$(D^{-1}WD)(g_{n}) = a_{n}d_{n}d_{n+1}^{-1}g_{n+1} = b_{n}d_{n+1}d_{n+1}^{-1}g_{n+1} = b_{n}g_{n+1} = V(g_{n}).$$
As $D^{-1}WD$ and $V$ are bounded linear operators because the sequences $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are bounded, and as they are equal on the orthonormal basis $\{g_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$, they are equal.

Thanks for the fast answer!
